# Deleting a file in Windows 7 skips the recycle bin and is deleted permanantly

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

When I delete a file, it bypasses the recycle bin and is deleted permanantly.

I've made sure the recycle bin's "Don't move files to the recycle bin" option is unchecked and it has a maximum size of 25,122MB

Presumably I've changed something at some point, I had a quick google but didn't see anything obvious.

If I drag a (small) file to to the recycle bin, I see the prompt "Are you sure you want to permanently delete this file?", selecting yes deletes the file, skipping the recycle bin.

I'm using Windows 7 (32-bit), build 7100 (7100.0.x86fre.winmain_win7rc.090421-1700)

The drive the OS is installed on is an SSD using the NTFS file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you checked the size of the size of the disk that the recycling bin is allowed to use?
  Might create a similar effect to deleting a large file.
- When you drag a file over the recycling bin what text comes up? Blue 'Move to Recycling Bin or Orange Alert 'Delete'?
- What build are you using?

Odd, my system doesn't give confirmation of either when dragged even though the box is ticked; but get confirmation on both from the keyboard.

You might wish to keep a copy of [recuva](http://www.recuva.com/) until this is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, greyDrifter. I've checked and the blue "move to recycle bin" arrow appears, but then dropping it displays a "delete this file perm.?" dialog. I've updated my answer with build info. I've bought a copy of Win7 that'll arrive in Oct, so I think I'll use recuva until then and prob use the win dvd to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

It honestly sounds like your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is stuck, as this is the behavior for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

The only other time a file will skip the recycle bin is when you delete of a network drive, or a non-NTFS drive. I am not aware of any other settings that control this behavior.

Comment: hehe, my shift key isn't stuck :-) I'll update my question with some drive info

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer to this question - sometimes I was given the option to recycle a file, and sometimes not.  I did all the usual checks of the Recycle Bin - settings, permissions etc., but no change.

I finally spotted the reason it wasn't working for me - a "Doh!" moment.  The files that I could recycle were open in "Computer" in Win Explorer.  The files I couldn't were open within "Network".

Maybe not your solution, but a simple one to consider.

Comment: You didn't contribute with anything new @Matthew Brindley already said in his answer "The only other time a file will skip the recycle bin is when you delete of a network drive, or a non-NTFS drive."