# Windows 7 cross-volume symlinks affecting recycle bin

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, recycle-bin

<sup>Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/34242/) but not identical.</sup>

**Scenario:**

`C:\Folder\Symlink\` is a symlink pointing to `E:\Folder\Folder\Target\`

**Problem:**

Deleting a file through `C:\Folder\Symlink\*` bypasses the Recycle Bin, even though both `C:` and `E:` have the Recycle Bin enabled. <s>This only seems to happen with cross-volume symlinks.</s>

**Example:**

1. Using the above symlink structure, create a file `C:\Folder\Symlink\somefile.txt`
2. Delete `C:\Folder\Symlink\somefile.txt` by using either the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key or right-click > Delete.
3. The prompt comes up for *immediate deletion*, instead of offering to send the file to the Recycle Bin.

**Question:**

Can anyone else reproduce this, and is there a fix?

### **Update:**

Did some more digging and was able to further isolate the issue.

In the list below, `Denied` specifies a folder that has access permissions revoked for the current user. All other folders have Full Control. Permissions are *not* inherited. Each folder has explicit permissions.

- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Denied\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? NO
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Allowed\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? YES
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Allowed\Denied\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? NO
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Allowed\Allowed\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? YES
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Denied\Allowed\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? YES
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Denied\Denied\Allowed\Target\` = Recycle Bin? NO
- `C:\Folder\Symlink\` => `E:\Denied\Denied\Denied\Target\` = Recycle Bin? NO

Adding at least two `Denied` folders *in a row* introduces this issue. It seems the shell is not able to see through through more than one consecutive unreadable folder?

Comment: I think this behavior is intrinsic to the symlink. After all, which recycle bin should it go to?

Comment: Why? That would defeat the purpose of a symlink.

Comment: Read the answer. That is what I mean. The purpose of a symlink is that it does not matter at all where the file "actually" is.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that permissions are the case.  The Recycle Bin is part of the Shell.  All the Shell cares about is if you have permission to delete the file **in the first place**.  Explicit permissions that are not inherited just don't make sense here. You  need to specify **the permission regarding the file itself**.  The file's permissions != the containing folder's permissions. If a file is hardlinked to two different folders, **it doesn't inherit permissions from both folders.**

Comment: I'll have to test this out also.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, nope, no fix.  It's "by-design".  If the delete dialog cannot determine the physical location of the file, the permanent delete dialog is shown instead.  With a symlink, the physical location of the file is "indeterminate" at best... so no-chance for the move-to-recycle bin option.

Comment: Huh? If the physical location were "indeterminate", symlinks would be useless, no?

Comment: Not at all.  The physical location is not the same as the path.  The same problem exists on network paths via UNC... or web-based files... etc.  If the delete dialog isn't provided physical location to the file (i.e. c:\filename), it's treated as if it came from somewhere else.  Symlinks aren't the same as hard links.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, **but I get the move to recycling bin prompt**.

### Cross volume link.

[image: Symblink]

### Hit Delete

[image: Delete]

Comment: Umm, I can't tell which one it goes to :)  The recycle bin is aggregated for local volumes. I'll have to get back with you on that.

Comment: Yeah, it shows up in the target's volume location (C in my case).

Comment: The two dialogs you show do not seem to have any relation to each other. Could you clarify?

Comment: @kreemoweet: I followed the OP's instructions. I posted these pics to show I got a different result.

Comment: Perhaps there's something about having physical and virtual locations available in the same paths.  i.e. c:\linked-dir => d:\linked-dir = fine... but c:\other-dir\linked-dir => d:\linked-dir = broken.

Comment: Works here. D:\Folder A\Link to B => C:\Folder B *which is Link to C* =>  c:\Folder C.  Delete still gives me the recycle bin.