# Recycle Bin not showing any items

Tags: recycle-bin

I have deleted multiple files from my system.

The Recycle Bin icon on the Desktop is also showing full but when I am exploring the Recycle Bin it is not displaying any items in it.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate Edition.

How to fix this type of issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have configurd your system to permanantly delete files http://superuser.com/questions/34242/deleting-a-file-in-windows-7-skips-the-recycle-bin-and-is-deleted-permanantly?rq=1

Comment: no it is not that way my recycle bin is containing items but i am not able to view them

Comment: i have gone through all of these type of question but not able to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unhiding the folders? you can do this by

-opening the recycle bin and in the left corner there should be a drop down menu called organize. If you go into that there should be a tab 'folder and search options', click on that and it should bring an external box up. Click 
the view tab and within that you can choose the option 'show hidden files, folders and drives'
if this does not help let me know

cheers neerg

Comment: sorry it is not working i tried every possible way

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually delete hidden folder `$RECYCLE.BIN` on yours disks.

Comment: i need to view those items first so any solution for that